# Issue in updating MS Access records using oledbcommand.executeNonQuery(), result not updating

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb, oledbcommand

I am posting a query first time here, So, Please ignore my formatting.

I am trying to update my .accdb file using update command, but result of `oledbcommand.executeNonQuery()` is `0` hence result is not updating in the database.

Though I am receiving no errors.

Here is what I am doing.

```
string vsql = string.Format("UPDATE DefTask_List SET [Action]=@Action WHERE  [SNo]=@SNo");
vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SNo", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", comboBox1.Text);

OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, vcon);
vcon.Open();
int k = vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
vcom.Dispose();
vcon.Close();
```

Please note that `SNo` is an `autonumber` in my .accdb file also with the same way I am inserting and deleting data but that is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support named parameters. The only matter is their orders.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters...
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

That's why your first `@Action` in `OleDbCommand` matches with `@SNo` in your `AddWithValue` and `@SNo` matches with your `@Action` in your `AddWithValue`.

Since probably you don't have a data like this, there will be no update operation.

Switch your parameter orders and use [`.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which is recommended instead of `AddWithValue`. It may generate unexpected results. Read;

- [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` instead of calling `.Dispose()` and `.Close()` methods manually.

```
using(OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand vcom = vcon.CreateCommand())
{
    vcom.CommandText = "UPDATE DefTask_List SET [Action]=@Action WHERE [SNo]=@SNo";
    vcom.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
    vcom.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = (int)row.Cells[0].Value;
    // I assume your column types are NVarchar2 and Int32
    vcon.Open();
    int k = vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. the code is working now after changing the order of command