# SQL update command return always 0

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access-2007

I wonder why this code doesn´t work; it always return zero (any affected row). The database is a Access database. I can insert and delete but not update the data. Its a Windows Forms C# App.

```
        string sql = "";
        try
        {
            string[] parametrosNomes = new string[3];
            parametrosNomes[0] = "@CatId";
            parametrosNomes[1] = "@CatNome";
            parametrosNomes[2] = "@CatDescricao";

            object[] parametrosValores = new object[3];
            parametrosValores[0] = oCateg.categoriaid;
            parametrosValores[1] = oCateg.categoriaNome;
            parametrosValores[2] = oCateg.categoriaDescricao;

            sql = "UPDATE Categorias SET categoriaNome = @CatNome, categoriaDescricao=@CatDescricao Where categoriaId=@CatId";
            int retorno = AcessoDB.CRUD(sql, parametrosNomes, parametrosValores);
            return retorno;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Note: In CRUD method I only filling the parameters and executing the sqlcommand

```
int retorno = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
return retorno;
```

I verified all parameters, the name of fields and the command is executed without errors but always return zero and does not update the table in database.

I can´t see nothing wrong in my code but it doesn´t work.

Can anyone open my eyes?

Comment: not sure about access databases.. connection string or something? Does it actually have any records where categorialId=@CatId?

Comment: Have you ever tried your query in your database manager like SSMS? Is it update in there? Did you debug your code? What is your query looks like when you add your parameter values? What is `AcessoDB` and `CRUD` exactly? Are you using OleDb .Net Provider? If you use OLE DB, it doesn't support named parameters. You need to provide them in same order that you add it in your command.

Comment: Post the code for `AcessoDB.CRUD` and people may be able to help you. Our ability to debug your code by reading your thoughts over TCP/IP is lacking.

Comment: and do not do this: `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }`. Use `throw;` without the exception to preserve it's stacktrace.

Comment: This might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103913/issue-in-updating-ms-access-records-using-oledbcommand-executenonquery-result - the parameters are not being passed in the order they are being used.

Comment: You may want to have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) before posting more of your code though.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to thank everyone for the answers.

The problem was solved : the parameters are not being passed in the order they are being used.

I'm just correct the parameters order:

```
string[] parametrosNomes = new string[3];
parametrosNomes[0] = "@CatNome";
parametrosNomes[1] = "@CatDescricao";
parametrosNomes[2] = "@CatId";
object[] parametrosValores = new object[3];
parametrosValores[0] = oCateg.categoriaNome;
parametrosValores[1] = oCateg.categoriaDescricao;
parametrosValores[2] = oCateg.categoriaid;
sql = "UPDATE Categorias SET categoriaNome = @CatNome, categoriaDescricao=@CatDescricao Where categoriaId=@CatId";
```

Now the table is being updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Parameters should be in the same sequence as in the sql. In the sql itself, you need to use '?'

```
    string sql = "";
    try
    {
        string[] parametrosNomes = new string[3];
        parametrosNomes[0] = "@CatNome";
        parametrosNomes[1] = "@CatDescricao";
        parametrosNomes[2] = "@CatCatId";

        object[] parametrosValores = new object[3];
        parametrosValores[0] = oCateg.categoriaNome;
        parametrosValores[1] = oCateg.categoriaDescricao;
        parametrosValores[2] = oCateg.categoriaid;

        sql = "UPDATE Categorias SET categoriaNome = ?, categoriaDescricao = ? Where categoriaId = ?";
        int retorno = AcessoDB.CRUD(sql, parametrosNomes, parametrosValores);
        return retorno;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had always thought using a dictionary that matched the values with the names (e.g., id = @id) in the query meant the order didn't matter when adding parameters to the OleDbCommand.Parameters list.  Indeed, I have never had this issue with .NET and Oracle or SQL Server databases.  However, with msaccess (or maybe it's OleDb) I found when I had the id parameter (see single line below) as the first entry in the OleDbCommand.Parameters list, ExecuteNonQuery always returned 0.  After moving the line to the end of the parameters list (id was used in the WHERE clause), ExecuteNonQuery returned 1 (the expected result).

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pi.Id);
```