# update data with 2 keys using oledb in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I made project in c# and connected it with database with 2 tables.
The first table is Tcostumers about costumer's details, works perfectly.
The second table is Treports about reports of every costumer for every year.
They keys are cid and cyear.
I succeeded making a button for insert new year for costumer.
The problem is making update button for update cinfo.
There is no error when I run the program but it doesn't save the info.
Here is my code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Treports
                                                SET cinfo = @cinfo
                                                    WHERE cid = @cid,
                                                          cyear = @cyear", connect);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cinfo", textBox2.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", textBox3.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cyear", textBox1.Text);

            try
            {
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception expe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
            }
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception expe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Specifically what is the problem?  are you getting an error, not able to create the button?  Does your computer catch on fire?  :>

Comment: I don't have any error.. It just does not save anything.

Comment: See this [posting][1] as it looks like your issue


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103913/issue-in-updating-ms-access-records-using-oledbcommand-executenonquery-result

Comment: That post for updating data with 1 key, I have 2.

Comment: You should replace the comma character `,` for keyword `AND` instead. _I don't understand why you're using a comma separator between conditionals._

A cleaner approach is like follows:
`@"UPDATE Treports SET cinfo = @cinfo WHERE cid = @cid AND year = @cyear"`
**I cannot post an answer since I do not have knowledges on OleDB.**

Comment: I did as you said, I switched the ',' for 'AND' and it is worked perfectly. tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Issue in updating MS Access records using oledbcommand.executeNonQuery(), result not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103913/issue-in-updating-ms-access-records-using-oledbcommand-executenonquery-result)

The issue is that OleDbCommand's do NOT support named parameters:

Replace:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cinfo", textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cyear", textBox1.Text);
```

With:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox1.Text);
```

I operate on an AS/400 at work that utilizes OleDbCommand's, and trust me when I say this is the biggest pain in the arse I've ever dealt with. And some of our tables have 10+ keys.

Comment: Actually it's more subtle than that. `System.Data.OleDb` allows us to use @placeholder names in the CommandText but it ignores the names and only pays attention to the position of the placeholders. That's why using `?` placeholders is recommended but not absolutely required.